# Facebook OpenGraph: Error while submitting the open graph item for Review

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to submit the open graph action for Facebook approval and it's keep rejecting with error message:

{Currently Ineligible for Submission.You, or this app's Open Graph Test User, must have published this action at least once.}

I have posted the custom open graph story many times using  a real Facebook account added as a tester and the Open Graph Test User account.

As explained in the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process document, Once we have successfully published your Open Graph story, we should be able to see sample stories within the developer console. But it is not displayed there also.

Can anyone please help on this?